# VB.NET Dataviualization.Charting conflicts with Melexis COM Object

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a program that connects to a LIN Master from Melexis to do LIN communication.

I've been using it well since the beginning of the year.

However, since I don't use the program every day, I don't know the exact date, but since sometime ago the program turned off for no reason.

I'm only bringing in the part of the code that is causing the symptoms.

The code was very short and didn't make any logical errors.

Here's the full code

```
Imports System.CodeDom
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports CommUnit
Imports MLXLINPSFModule

Public Class Form1
    Dim Form2Object As Form2 = Nothing

    Sub CreateDevice()
        Dim PSFMan As MLXLINPSFManager
        PSFMan = New MLXLINPSFManager       
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CreateDevice()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If Form2Object Is Nothing Then
            Form2Object = New Form2()
            Form2Object.Show()
        Else
            Form2Object.Close()
            Form2Object = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form2 is nothing more than a single chart added through the designer.
[Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmn0S.png)

I figured this out through some experimentation.

1. press button 1 to run the PSFMan = New MLXLINPSFManager statement and press button 2 to raise a StackOverFlow Exception.
2. The exception is thrown in the first line of Form2's InitializeComponent(), which is

   System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();

If you look at the COMObject description in Melexis, it says

> This object is created only once and is destroyed when the library is unmapped from process address space. Each
> subsequent request for this object returns the same instance.

The .NET Framework version I am using is 4.8.1.

At first I suspected it was due to a change in the .NET Framework with Windows Update.

So I downloaded and ran it with version 4.7.2, but it's still the same symptom.

Please Help Me!!

Comment: There is usually more information about the error please add it to your question and which line to hrows the error

Comment: The first line in Form2's InitializeComponent() causes an error
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();

Comment: according to https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea?view=netframework-4.8.1 you have another class for chartarea